# Need help fixing language selection and kernel shutdown issue in voice assistant project using Python

Tags: python, kivy, speech-recognition, chatbot

I am working on a Python-based voice assistant project to guide university visitors. The assistant uses a JSON file to store intents and responses, and switches to ChatGPT if the input doesn't match the stored patterns closely enough. The UI allows users to select their preferred language (English or French) by clicking a button.

However, I am facing two major issues:

I am unsure about the correct way to change the language once the user has made their selection. My current approach seems inefficient, and I would appreciate guidance on how to optimize this part of the code.

After the user selects a language, the UI becomes unresponsive, and eventually, the kernel shuts down. I suspect this might be related to the way I am handling language selection or the audio processing, but I am not certain.

Any suggestions or advice on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code after trainig and saving of the correspondant model :

```
import json
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import openai
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import sys

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
# load intents from JSON file english
with open(r'C:\Users\LEOPARD\Desktop\partie mouad\intents.json') as file:
    intents = json.load(file)
# create lists of words, labels, and training data
words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []

# loop through intents and patterns to create training data
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        # tokenize and lemmatize words in pattern
        wrds = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)]
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent['responses'][0])
    if intent['responses'][0] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent['responses'][0])

# sort and remove duplicates from words and labels lists
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
labels = sorted(list(set(labels)))
openai.api_key = "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"
model_engine = "davinci"
model = keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('voice', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_DAVID_11.0')
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)


patterns = []
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for phrase in intent['patterns']:
        patterns.append(phrase)

def calculate_similarity(text, patterns):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform([text] + patterns)
    similarity = cosine_similarity(matrix)[0, 1:]
    return similarity

def get_most_similar(text, patterns):
    similarity = calculate_similarity(text, patterns)
    most_similar_index = np.argmax(similarity)
    return patterns[most_similar_index]

def predict_response(text):
    # initialize lemmatizer
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    
    # tokenize and lemmatize words in input text
    pattern_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text)]
    
    # create bag-of-words representation of input text
    pattern_bag = []
    for word in words:
        pattern_bag.append(1) if word in pattern_words else pattern_bag.append(0)
    
    # make prediction using trained model
    prediction = model.predict(np.array([pattern_bag]))
    
    # return response with highest predicted probability
    return labels[np.argmax(prediction)]

def chatbot_response(text):
    if text.lower() == 'stop':
        return True, ''
    most_similar_pattern = get_most_similar(text, patterns)
    similarity = calculate_similarity(text, [most_similar_pattern])[0]
    print(similarity)
    if similarity > 0.4:
        response = predict_response(text)
        return False, response
    else:
        completion = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-003",
            prompt=text,
            max_tokens=40,
            n=1,
            stop=None,
            temperature=0.5,
        )
        return False, completion.choices[0].text
def run_chatbot(selected_lang):
    if selected_lang.lower() == 'french':
        engine.setProperty('voice', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_FR-FR_HORTENSE_11.0')
        engine.say(f"comment est ce que je peux vous aider?")
    else:
        engine.setProperty('voice', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_DAVID_11.0')
        engine.say(f"Hey how can I help.")
    engine.runAndWait()

    while True:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio_data = recognizer.listen(source)
        try:
            if selected_lang.lower() == 'french':
                text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data, language='fr-FR')
            else:
                text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data, language='en-US')
            print(f"You said: {text}")
            stop, response = chatbot_response(text)
            if stop:
                break
            engine.say(response)
            engine.runAndWait()
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Sorry, I could not understand the audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            engine.say("Error occurred while requesting results from Google Speech Recognition service: {0}".format(e))
            engine.runAndWait()
class LanguageSelectionApp(App):
    lang = StringProperty("")

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        
        image = Image(source=r'C:\Users\LEOPARD\Desktop\partie mouad\image.png', size_hint=(1, 0.7))
        layout.add_widget(image)
        
        button_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1, 0.3))
        english_button = Button(text="English", on_press=self.on_english_click)
        french_button = Button(text="French", on_press=self.on_french_click)

        button_layout.add_widget(english_button)
        button_layout.add_widget(french_button)
        
        layout.add_widget(button_layout)
        
        return layout

    def on_english_click(self, _):
        self.lang = "english"
        self.stop()

    def on_french_click(self, _):
        self.lang = "french"
        self.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Store the original sys.argv
    original_argv = sys.argv

    # Set sys.argv to include only the script name
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]

    app = LanguageSelectionApp()
    app.run()

    selected_lang = app.lang

    # Restore the original sys.argv
    sys.argv = original_argv

    if selected_lang:
        run_chatbot(selected_lang)
```

And here is what I used to train the model:

```
import json
import nltk
import numpy as np
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
# load intents from JSON file
with open('intents.json') as file:
    intents = json.load(file)

# initialize lemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

# create lists of words, labels, and training data
words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []

# loop through intents and patterns to create training data
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        # tokenize and lemmatize words in pattern
        wrds = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)]
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent['responses'][0])
    if intent['responses'][0] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent['responses'][0])

# sort and remove duplicates from words and labels lists
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
labels = sorted(list(set(labels)))

# create bag-of-words representation of training data
training = []
output = []
out_empty = [0] * len(labels)
for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
    bag = []
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in doc else bag.append(0)
    output_row = out_empty[:]
    output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1
    training.append(bag)
    output.append(output_row)

# convert training data and output to numpy arrays
training = np.array(training)
output = np.array(output)

# define and compile neural network model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(len(training[0]),), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(len(output[0]), activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# train model on training data
model.fit(training, output, epochs=1000, batch_size=8)
model.save('model.h5')
```

***The Json file : ***

```
{"intents":
[
  {"patterns": ["hey","hello","what's up?","how is it going?","hi","good day"],
    "responses": ["Hello Sir!,what can I do for you?"]},
  {"patterns": ["please take me to the cafeteria","i want to go to the cafeteria","take me to the cafeteria","cafeteria","take me"],
    "responses": ["sure! follow me"]},
  {"patterns": ["where is the director's office","the director's office","director's office","director office"],
    "responses": ["the director's office is located in the bloc A just in front the cafeteria, say okay if you'd like me to go there"]},
  {"patterns": ["Pouvez-vous me conduire au salon étudiant ?"],
"responses": ["Le salon étudiant se trouve au dernier étage du bâtiment principal, c'est un lieu commun où les étudiants peuvent se détendre, socialiser et prendre des collations. Suivez-moi si vous voulez y aller."]},
{"patterns": ["Où puis-je trouver la salle d'art ?"],
"responses": ["La salle d'art se trouve dans le bloc des arts créatifs au deuxième étage, c'est un endroit idéal pour les étudiants pour explorer leurs talents artistiques. Suivez-moi si vous voulez y aller."]}
    ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the [stop()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.stop) method of the app in your `on_english_click()` or `on_french_click()` methods:

> If you use this method, the whole application will stop by issuing a
> call to stopTouchApp().

Try just removing the calls to `stop()`. Perhaps you should just run the `run_chatbot()` method in another thread.